# Generalized Measure of Central Tendency

Tags: statistics, reference-request, average

I was wondering if there is some general notion of central tendency. I had in mind the following axiomatization: A measure of central tendency on a totally ordered set $X$ is a family of functions $\mu_n : X^n \to X$ such that

1. If $a_i \geq b_i$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, then $\mu_n(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \geq \mu_n(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$.
2. If $a_{n+1} \geq \mu_n(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, then $\mu_{n + 1} (a_1, \ldots, a_{n + 1}) \geq \mu_n (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$. The same statement holds with $\geq$ replaced by $\leq$ or $=$.
3. $\min(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \leq \mu_n(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \leq \max(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$
4. If $\sigma \in S_n$, then $\mu_n(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = \mu_n(a_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, a_{\sigma(n)})$ (the $\mu_n$ are symmetric).

It seems like everything we call a measure of central tendency satisfies these axioms. For example, the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means; median; and mode (when it is unique) all satisfy these axioms. Based on this, these axioms seem general enough, but are they too general? Do they allow functions which we wouldn't call measures of central tendency?

I'm not that invested in the axiomatization I've layed out above. I'm mostly interested in whether or not this sort of thing has been written about. How have others attempted to generalize the notion of "central tendency?"

Comment: I should add that I'm not even sure a totally ordered set is the best setting for generalizing measures of central tendency.

Comment: It looks like $\min$ and $\max$ also satisfy your requirements, which might not meet some ideas about *central*.  Meanwhile median and mode are not always uniquely defined: what is the mode of $1,1,5,5$?

Comment: Ah, I meant to add that to the original post. I meant to say something like "mode (when it is unique)." Also, the point about $\min$ and $\max$ is a good one. Perhaps replacing some of the inequalities with strict inequalities would be better, but for now I'll leave them as they are. As I said, I'm much more interested in the idea of a generalized measure of central tendency than in my (shabby) attempt at axiomatizing it.